# Why does my program have no output?

Tags: python, data-structures

I wrote a program to answer this question. It says that my program has no output.

Question:
Write a program to read through the mbox-short.txt and figure out the distribution by hour of the day for each of the messages. You can pull the hour out from the 'From ' line by finding the time and then splitting the string a second time using a colon.

```
From sample.user@example.com.za Sat Jan  5 09:14:16 2008
```

Once you have accumulated the counts for each hour, print out the counts, sorted by hour as shown below.

Desired Output:

```
04 3
06 1
07 1
09 2
10 3
11 6
14 1
15 2
16 4
17 2
18 1
19 1
```

My code:

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    if not line.startswith('From'): 
        continue

        words = line.split()

        time = words[5]

        timesplit = time.split(':')

        hour  = timesplit[0]

        for x in hour:
            counts[x] = counts.get(x, 0) + 1

lists = list()

for key, val in counts.items():
    lists.append( (key, val) )
    lists.sort(reverse=True)

for val, key in lists:
    print key, val
```

Comment: are you sure that your code is pasted  correctly into this page ?  then the code after `words = line.splite()` will be never executed since it has same indent with `continue`

Comment: I first have to check whether a line starts with 'From'. If doesn't the continue makes the code run again and again until it finds a line starting with 'From'. Then it executes the following code.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you make the mistake by putting the following codes into the if indentedStatementBlock.

```
    words = line.split()

    time = words[5]

    timesplit = time.split(':')

    hour  = timesplit[0]

    for x in hour:
        counts[x] = counts.get(x, 0) + 1
```

Answer (score 0):

You have an indentation problem. Nothing beyond ***continue*** in your loop will ever be processed. I would recommend you change the if statement to `if line.startswith('From'):` and remove the continue altogether.

Why are you doing this `for x in hour:` ? hour appears to be a two character string, so when you iterate over '08', x will equal '0' then '8'. Just count the hour.

Also, counts.items() creates a list of tuples, so you dont need to iterate over that list to create a new list of tuples.

```
lists = counts.items()
lists.sort(reverse=True)
```

Additionally, you should make a habit of closing the file again.

Edit:
For completeness sake, this is how I would approach the same problem:

```
from collections import Counter

def extract_hour(line):

    return line.split()[5].split(':')[0]

lists = Counter(extract_hour(line) for line in open("mbox-short.txt") if line.startswith('From')).items()
```

Answer (score 0):

Through trial and error and a bit help from the suggestions from the previous answers here, I have come up with the solution and my code worked!

```
name = raw_input("Enter file:")
if len(name) < 1 : name = "mbox-short.txt"
handle = open(name)

counts = dict()

for line in handle:
    line = line.rstrip()
    if line == '': continue
    if line.startswith('From '):
        words = line.split()
        time = words[5]
        tsplit = time.split(":")
        counts[tsplit[0]] = counts.get(tsplit[0], 0) + 1


lists = list()

for key, val in counts.items():
    lists.append( (key, val) )

lists.sort()

for val, key in lists:
    print val, key
```